# How to get group/role names for the user

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, adal, asp.net-core-webapi

I have SPA application that uses adal.js. I can login ok and renew the token. I noticed that in the user profile there are no groups so I changed the manifest in the Azure AD:

```
Old: "groupMembershipClaims": null
New: "groupMembershipClaims": "All"
```

After that change I can see the groups array in client side but it contains only GUIDs. Server side (.NET Core Web Api) it is the same thing. I can see the group in the claims but the name is null. Is this because the group is synced to Azure AD from local corporate AD?

I would like to use the Authorize attribute to restrict some operations to users that are part of certain group. E.g.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Edit: Is the role same as group?

I would also like to have this information on the client side so that I can disable some buttons etc.

Comment: Roles and Groups are not the same. Groups are what you are used to from on-prem AD. Roles are per application. You can define them in the portal in the application settings, and assign users to them. By default Roles are part of the JWT token, and groups are not. Unless you use ``groupMembershipClaims``, as you have already figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get the ids of the groups in the claims. Typically you would not want to use the group names anyway, since they can be changed easily by anyone. The GUID can't be changed so it's a bit more reliable.

I think you *could* specify `RoleClaimType` to be the groups claim when configuring authentication, and then use the GUIDs in `[Authorize]`. Personally I would find it a bit confusing. In classic MVC I would write a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that would check that the user's group claims contain the required value. It would not be difficult to make it so that it allows you to specify the group as a string, and then gets the group GUID from configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @rasmusw groups and roles are different. In our case the access rights are given using groups (synced from the on premises AD) so I decided to do the following

**Configure that groups are actually roles**

```cs
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
    {
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            RoleClaimType = "groups",
        }
    });
```

**Hard code object ids with sane names**

```cs
public const string Sales = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

**Use the sane names in Authorize attribute**

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = Sales)]
```

It is not the prettiest solution but it seems to work. It should be noted that ClaimsPrincipal contains only the object ids of the groups. I decided to inject custom IUserContext that contains Roles like "Sales", "Marketing" so that I don't have to deal with the object ids in the code. With that I can easily use something like:

```cs
user.IsInRole(Sales)
```

Comment: I mentioned this as a possible solution in my answer, but one problem is that now you are hard-coded to a group, and it cannot be changed via configuration settings. I have a few cases where a user might have access to the testing environment, but we don't want them to have the same access in production.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint for people who will try this kind of solution (groups for roles). you might face an issue after publishing your website into azure, which was my case and the solution is to add the following lines to your web.config :

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules>
    <remove name="RoleManager" /> 
....
  </modules>
```

Comment: I did already lol